# Reading a logging level from JSON but not interpreting it as a string

Tags: python, json, logging

I have a JSON file which has a dictionary and one of the values is the following

```
{
  "loglevel":"logging.INFO",
```

Then when I am setting up my logger (as below) it is giving me an error:

> ValueError: Unknown level: 'logging.INFO'

The reason I believe is that it is putting the `logger.setLevel` as a string. Any ideas how to go about it?

```
with open("export_tool_config.json", "r") as f:
    data_load=json.load(f)

log_level = data_load['loglevel']

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(log_level)
```

I need `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` and not `logger.setLevel('logging.INFO')`.

I tried making the parameter hardcoded and works fine.

Comment: Can you modify the data format? `logger.setLevel("INFO")` should work. Otherwise, you'll need to write a function to transform your supported values into the values supported by `setLevel`.

Comment: You can try the hacky `log_level = eval(data_load['loglevel'])`. Be sure, to put it in a try-except block though.

Comment: You can simply convert `"logging.INFO"` to `"INFO"` by using `log_level.split(".")[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a dictionary translating strings to logging values:

```
log_levels = {
    "logging.INFO": logging.INFO,
    "logging.DEBUG": logging.DEBUG
    # etc.
}
```

(You can drop the initial `logging.` in the string as it is not necessary)

Refer to that dictionary when setting log level:

```
logger.setLevel(log_levels[log_level])
```

Now you can just refer to it in configuration file:

```
{
  "loglevel":"logging.INFO"
}
```

Note: logging does support using just strings as log levels - `logger.setLevel("INFO")`